# What does "libraries not eligible" mean as part of the application review process?

Tags: development, application-development, application-submission

I read the [application review process](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviews) and I' ve got a question. In the "What Apps Are Eligible" section there is something which I don't understand:

- No other software can depend on the application being submitted (e.g. development libraries are not eligible).

Somebody can explain it with an example please..

Answer (score 5):

It's saying that applications reviewed by the Application Review Board have to be standalone in that they can be used (and therefore tested) straight away without needing to use them as part of another application.

The Application Review Board is there to test software for developers but only software that they *can* test. They don't want to spend hours building it into something else just to be able to test it.

So a media player would be allowed but a media codec (that has to be built into a player to be tested) would not.

Comment: Okay, But if I have an application wich is a GUI for a commandline app. And the commandline app isn't in the repository, but it is packaging into my app installer deb. Is this allowed?

Comment: Good question. IMO they *should* review it if you provide your dependencies in a package-able format... But I think you'd have to contact them directly to find out for sure.